# How to add an element to an enumeration (XNA SpriteEffects example)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

To flip a sprite, in XNA I can use a variable as argument in an overload of the `Draw` method:

```cs
SpriteEffects flip_effect_ = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
// or
flip_effect_ = SpriteEffects.FlipVertically;
// or
flip_effect_ = SpriteEffects.None;
```

If I want to flip a sprite **both vertically and horizontally** I can do:

```
flip_effect_ = SpriteEffects.FlipVertically | SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
```

So, `SpriteEffects` enumeration contains only the first three values. ([MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spriteeffects.aspx) Is there a way to extend that enumeration and add, for example, "FlipBoth"? I will use it:

```
flip_effect_ = SpriteEffects.FlipBoth;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

However, you can create a static class with custom constants like:

```
static class MySpriteEffects
{
    public const SpriteEffects FlipVertically = SpriteEffect.FlipVertically;
    public const SpriteEffects FlipHorizontally = SpriteEffect.FlipHorizontally;
    public const SpriteEffects FlipBoth = SpriteEffect.FlipVertically | SpriteEffects.FlipHozizontally;
}
```

and use it as

```
.Draw(..., MySpriteEffects.FlipBoth);
```

You can add the `FlipVertically` and `FlipHorizontally` to be consistent throughout your project. But you can also just leave them away.